# How to change FreshTabbedNavigationContainer tabbed page to top and change icon and font size for ios in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage, freshmvvm

I have using freshmvvm for my xamarin forms application. FreshTabbedNavigationContainer tabbed page is working fine with android. I have customized the android tabbed page font size, font color, image size. But in IOS I don't know how to change the tab bar from bottom to top like in android and how to change the size of the icon and font. Please anyone suggest me to done this. My tabbed page code is below,

```
var tabbedPage = new FreshTabbedNavigationContainer();            
tabbedPage.AddTab<FirstPageModel>("One", "icon.png");
tabbedPage.AddTab<SecondPageModel>("Two", "icon.png");
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage);
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(tabbedPage, false);
```

I have changed the tabbar scrollable using custom renderer for android like this,

```
public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
{
    base.OnViewAdded(child);
    var tabLayout = child as TabLayout;
    if (tabLayout != null)
    {
        tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeScrollable;
    }
}
```

How to change the tab bar as scrollable for ios. In my tabbed page, the space between text and icon is zero. Please refer the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Take a look at the Github that i have linked in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

[Naxam's](https://github.com/NAXAM/toptabbedpage-xamarin-forms) GitHub has sort of a similar implementation using a Customized version of Xamarin Forms TabbedPage, But since `FreshTabbedNavigationContainer` inherits from the same(TabbedPage) you can just use it instead and it should work like a charm.

```
public class TopTabbedPage : FreshTabbedNavigationContainer
{
    public TopTabbedPage()
    {
        //BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        //BarTextColor = Color.White;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty BarIndicatorColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(BarIndicatorColor),
        typeof(Color),
        typeof(TopTabbedPage),
        Color.White,
        BindingMode.OneWay);
    public Color BarIndicatorColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BarIndicatorColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarIndicatorColorProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty SwipeEnabledColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(SwipeEnabled),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(TopTabbedPage),
        true,
        BindingMode.OneWay);
    public bool SwipeEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(SwipeEnabledColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SwipeEnabledColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And then the renderer would look something like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TopTabbedPage), typeof(TopTabbedRenderer))]

namespace Naxam.Controls.Platform.iOS
{
using Platform = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform;
using Forms = Xamarin.Forms.Forms;

public partial class TopTabbedRenderer :
    UIViewController
{
    public static void Init()
    {
    }

    UIColor _defaultBarColor;
    bool _defaultBarColorSet;
    bool _loaded;
    Size _queuedSize;
    int lastSelectedIndex;

    Page Page => Element as Page;

    UIPageViewController pageViewController;

    protected UIViewController SelectedViewController;
    protected IList<UIViewController> ViewControllers;

    protected IPageController PageController
    {
        get { return Page; }
    }

    protected TopTabbedPage Tabbed
    {
        get { return (TopTabbedPage)Element; }
    }

    protected TabsView TabBar;
    private NSLayoutConstraint tabBarHeight;

    public TopTabbedRenderer()
    {
        ViewControllers = new UIViewController[0];

        pageViewController = new UIPageViewController(
            UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll,
            UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal,
            UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.None
        );

        TabBar = new TabsView
        {
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        };
        TabBar.TabsSelectionChanged += HandleTabsSelectionChanged;
    }

    public override void DidRotate(UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        base.DidRotate(fromInterfaceOrientation);

        View.SetNeedsLayout();
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        PageController.SendAppearing();
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    }

    public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
        PageController.SendDisappearing();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.AddSubview(TabBar);

        AddChildViewController(pageViewController);
        View.AddSubview(pageViewController.View);
        pageViewController.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        pageViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);


        var views = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(
            new NSObject[] {
            TabBar,
            pageViewController.View
        },
            new NSObject[] {
            (NSString) "tabbar",
            (NSString) "content"
        }
        );

        View.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:|-0-[tabbar]-0-[content]-0-|",
                                                                0,
                                                                null,
                                                                views));
        View.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|-0-[tabbar]-0-|",
                                                                0,
                                                                null,
                                                                views));
        View.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|-0-[content]-0-|",
                                                                0,
                                                                null,
                                                                views));


        tabBarHeight = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
            TabBar,
            NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
            NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            1, 68
        );
        TabBar.AddConstraint(tabBarHeight);

        if (pageViewController.ViewControllers.Length == 0
            && lastSelectedIndex >= 0 || lastSelectedIndex < ViewControllers.Count)
        {
            pageViewController.SetViewControllers(
                new[] { ViewControllers[lastSelectedIndex] },
               UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,
               true, null
            );
        }

        UpdateSwipe(Tabbed.SwipeEnabled);
        pageViewController.DidFinishAnimating += HandlePageViewControllerDidFinishAnimating;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            PageController?.SendDisappearing();

            if (Tabbed != null)
            {
                Tabbed.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
                Tabbed.PagesChanged -= OnPagesChanged;
                TabBar.TabsSelectionChanged -= HandleTabsSelectionChanged;
            }

            if (pageViewController != null)
            {
                pageViewController.WeakDataSource = null;
                pageViewController.DidFinishAnimating -= HandlePageViewControllerDidFinishAnimating;
                pageViewController?.Dispose();
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected virtual void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ElementChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    UIViewController GetViewController(Page page)
    {
        var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(page);
        return renderer?.ViewController;
    }

    void OnPagePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName != Page.TitleProperty.PropertyName)
            return;

        if (!(sender is Page page) || page.Title is null)
            return;

        TabBar.ReplaceItem(page.Title, Tabbed.Children.IndexOf(page));
    }

    void OnPagesChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Apply((o, i, c) => SetupPage((Page)o, i), (o, i) => TeardownPage((Page)o, i), Reset);

        SetControllers();

        UIViewController controller = null;
        if (Tabbed.CurrentPage != null)
        {
            controller = GetViewController(Tabbed.CurrentPage);
        }

        if (controller != null && controller != SelectedViewController)
        {
            SelectedViewController = controller;
            var index = ViewControllers.IndexOf(SelectedViewController);
            MoveToByIndex(index);
            TabBar.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(TabbedPage.CurrentPage))
        {
            var current = Tabbed.CurrentPage;
            if (current == null)
                return;

            var controller = GetViewController(current);
            if (controller == null)
                return;

            SelectedViewController = controller;
            var index = ViewControllers.IndexOf(SelectedViewController);
            MoveToByIndex(index);
            TabBar.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == TabbedPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateBarBackgroundColor();
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == TabbedPage.BarTextColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateBarTextColor();
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == TopTabbedPage.BarIndicatorColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateBarIndicatorColor();
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == TopTabbedPage.SwipeEnabledColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateSwipe(Tabbed.SwipeEnabled);
        }
    }

    public override UIViewController ChildViewControllerForStatusBarHidden()
    {
        var current = Tabbed.CurrentPage;
        if (current == null)
            return null;

        return GetViewController(current);
    }

    void UpdateSwipe(bool swipeEnabled)
    {
        pageViewController.WeakDataSource = swipeEnabled ? this : null;
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var page in Tabbed.Children)
        {
            SetupPage(page, i++);
        }
    }

    void SetControllers()
    {
        var list = new List<UIViewController>();
        var titles = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < Tabbed.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            var child = Tabbed.Children[i];
            var v = child as VisualElement;
            if (v == null)
                continue;

            var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(v);
            if (renderer == null) continue;

            list.Add(renderer.ViewController);

            titles.Add(Tabbed.Children[i].Title);
        }
        ViewControllers = list.ToArray();
        TabBar.SetItems(titles);
    }

    void SetupPage(Page page, int index)
    {
        IVisualElementRenderer renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(page);
        if (renderer == null)
        {
            renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(page);
            Platform.SetRenderer(page, renderer);
        }

        page.PropertyChanged -= OnPagePropertyChanged;
        page.PropertyChanged += OnPagePropertyChanged;
    }

    void TeardownPage(Page page, int index)
    {
        page.PropertyChanged -= OnPagePropertyChanged;

        Platform.SetRenderer(page, null);
    }

    void UpdateBarBackgroundColor()
    {
        if (Tabbed == null || TabBar == null)
            return;

        var barBackgroundColor = Tabbed.BarBackgroundColor;

        if (!_defaultBarColorSet)
        {
            _defaultBarColor = TabBar.BackgroundColor;

            _defaultBarColorSet = true;
        }

        TabBar.BackgroundColor = barBackgroundColor.ToUIColor();
    }

    void UpdateBarTextColor()
    {
        TabBar.TextColor = Tabbed.BarTextColor.ToUIColor();
    }

    void UpdateBarIndicatorColor()
    {
        TabBar.IndicatorColor = Tabbed.BarIndicatorColor.ToUIColor();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: there is no any reference for TabsView in your renderer. Please see the attached image in my code.

Comment: There are multiple files in use that is the reason i have linked the github, i cannot add it all here it will take too much time check the github please

Comment: I am using .NetFramework 2.0. Your github source contains **MaterialControls** which is not supported to my framework. Please suggest any other solution without changing the .NetFramework version.

Comment: You mean .NetStandard 2.0?

Comment: Yes, .NetStandard 2.0

Comment: I am pretty sure all of that code can be used in a .Net Standard enviroment as well